# iOS ad-hoc distributed app with link not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to create an ad-hoc IPA distribution for an iOS app. I did that by going to Xcode > Product > Archive
I followed this [link](https://dev.to/gualtierofr/ad-hoc-distribution-for-ios-1524)

However I'm getting below error "(null)" is Already installed "(null)" has the same bundle id as (null)..
If I drag IPA file directly via Itunes it works fine.

I created an html file with manifest link. It's an https link (on local server with certificates created by openssl)

html file code below

```
<a href='itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://myhost/files/manifest.plist'>Download IPA</a>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://myhost/files/ios app.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://myhost/files/image.57x57.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://myhost/files/image.512x512.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.company.ios-app</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>platform-identifier</key>
                <string>com.apple.platform.iphoneos</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>ios app</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to install the ipa? Are you using an Https link? Are you linking to the manifest file?

Comment: Yes i created a https link on my local server and linked it wtih manifest file. I've updated this detail in my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove space " " in software-package name
replace

```
<string>https://myhost/files/ios app.ipa</string>
```

with

```
<string>https://myhost/files/iosapp.ipa</string>
```

This fixed for me.